# Zend Gdata PHP API - How to set/get 'color' property for events

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata-api, gdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Calendar API - PHP - set event’s color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346277/google-calendar-api-php-set-events-color)

How do you set/get the 'color' property for events in Google Calendar?

There is no documentation for this.

It should be a case of simply...

```
$event->color = "red";
```

like you would do if you were updating the text...

```
$event->title = "hello";
```

but the exception is saying "no such property".

This is for the PHP API Zend Gdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you cannot set the color of a single event through the Google Calendar GData API, according to the API [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingEvents), even if you can do it on Google Calendar's web UI.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation Imi.

Comment: Do you know of a way to **get** the color of an event?

Comment: Just for reference on future visitors, you can do it already with  API V3 [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors) but you'll need to forget zend gdata though