# Google Calendar API - PHP - set event's color

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

How do we set a color when inserting an event with Google Calendar API (PHP)?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a PHP function I wrote and the portions of the PHP client library I extracted to allow me to create events in my calendar, delete events and so forth but the code is just to show you where the colorId needs to be set and the syntax to make it work.

The colors Google will show for each of the first 11 integers you can set colorId to.

1 blue

2 green

3 purple

4 red

5 yellow

6 orange

7 turquoise

8 gray

9 bold blue

10 bold green

11 bold red

```
function calendar_update($heading,$details,$address,$calendar_name,$start_time,$end_time,$event_id = "")
{
    $client = get_google_client($calendar_name); // ID of your Google calendar
    $capi = new GoogleCalendarApi($client);

    $event['event_time']['start_time'] = $start_time; // Start time of event
    $event['event_time']['end_time'] = $end_time;     // End time of the event
    $event['summary'] = $heading;                     // The title of the event
    $event['location'] = $address;                    // Address field of event
    $event['description'] = $details;                 // Body of the event
    $event['colorId'] = 3;                            // colorId of event (see above)
    $event['attendees'] = $calendar_name;

    try 
    {
        $event_id = $capi->CreateCalendarEvent($calendar_name, $event, 0,
             $event['event_time'], "Australia/Sydney", $_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) 
    {
        $result = $e->getMessage();
        return("ERROR\t$e");
    }
    return($event_id);
}



class GoogleCalendarApi
{
    public function GetAccessToken($client_id, $redirect_uri, $client_secret, $code) {    
        $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';            

        $curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_uri . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&code='. $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code';
        $ch = curl_init();        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);    
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);        
        if($http_code != 200) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to receieve access token');

        return $data;
    }

    public function GetUserCalendarTimezone($access_token) {
        $url_settings = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/settings/timezone';

        $ch = curl_init();        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_settings);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token));    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true); //echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);        
        if($http_code != 200) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to get timezone');

        return $data['value'];
    }

    public function GetCalendarsList($access_token) {
        $url_parameters = array();

        $url_parameters['fields'] = 'items(id,summary,timeZone)';
        $url_parameters['minAccessRole'] = 'owner';

        $url_calendars = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?'. http_build_query($url_parameters);

        $ch = curl_init();        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_calendars);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token));    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true); //echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);        
        if($http_code != 200) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to get calendars list');

        return $data['items'];
    }

    public function CreateCalendarEvent($calendar_id, $summary, $all_day, $event_time, $event_timezone, $access_token) {
        $url_events = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events';

        $curlPost = $summary;
//        $curlPost = array('summary' => $summary);
        if($all_day == 1) {
            $curlPost['start'] = array('date' => $event_time['event_date']);
            $curlPost['end'] = array('date' => $event_time['event_date']);
        }
        else {
            $curlPost['start'] = array('dateTime' => $event_time['start_time'], 'timeZone' => $event_timezone);
            $curlPost['end'] = array('dateTime' => $event_time['end_time'], 'timeZone' => $event_timezone);
        }
        $ch = curl_init();        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_events);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curlPost));    
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);        
        if($http_code != 200) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to create event');

        return $data['id'];
    }

    public function UpdateCalendarEvent($event_id, $calendar_id, $summary, $all_day, $event_time, $event_timezone, $access_token) {
        $url_events = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events/' . $event_id;

        $curlPost = $summary;
//        $curlPost = array('summary' => $summary);
        if($all_day == 1) {
            $curlPost['start'] = array('date' => $event_time['event_date']);
            $curlPost['end'] = array('date' => $event_time['event_date']);
        }
        else {
            $curlPost['start'] = array('dateTime' => $event_time['start_time'], 'timeZone' => $event_timezone);
            $curlPost['end'] = array('dateTime' => $event_time['end_time'], 'timeZone' => $event_timezone);
        }
        $ch = curl_init();        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_events);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curlPost));    
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);        
        if($http_code != 200) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to update event Code: ' . $http_code);
    }

    public function DeleteCalendarEvent($event_id, $calendar_id, $access_token) {
        $url_events = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events/' . $event_id;

        $ch = curl_init();        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_events);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));        
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($http_code != 204) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to delete event');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set the optional `colorId` property when [creating an event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). You can retrieve the list of colours from the [colors endpoint](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get).

Comment: To see the event colors i made this: https://jsfiddle.net/ztjga41q/

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find each idColor for your color that you want to insert for events 
[Google Calendar id Color for events](https://www.eduardopereira.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/google_calendar_api_event_color_chart.png)

Comment: link returns 404