# Changing color of a newly inserted Google Calender API event

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to insert a new event to my Google Calendar. While inserting, i want to change the color of the event as it appears on Google Calendar. 
What I have so far is this:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
   'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2018-09-14T00:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/New_York'
    ),
   'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2018-09-21T23:59:59-07:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/New_York'
    ),
   'backgroundColor' => "#C1292E"
));
    $parameter = array ('colorRgbFormat' => true);
    $calendarId = 'someemail@gmail.com';
    $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, $parameter);
```

It says in the documentation to set *colorRgbFormat* to true if you want to set the color: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert#examples

The problem is, the way I'm setting it is wrong.

How do I set *colorRgbFormat* as a parameter in php if I want to change the color of an inserted event?

Comment: this link may be helpful for you [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#colorId)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of an event using the following:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setColorId(10);
```

See [Google's API Docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) for further info.
Also I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346277/google-calendar-api-php-set-events-color) to be quite informative.

**Note**: This only changes the icon color of the event (see screenshot below). 
[image: Event icons]
It does not change the background color of the event. As far as I can tell, there is no way to change the background of the event (even in the Web UI it's not possible).

The functionality that the OP is referring to in their question regarding the background color is in reference to the [CalendarList#insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert#examples) API call - this is when you want to insert an existing calendar into your calendar list and not connected to editing configs for events.

Hope this helps! :-)