# How can I query Google Calendar color labels?

Tags: google-calendar-api

In my Google Workspace account, I use [color label strings](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/12377581) in Calendar to track time. I want to use these to automate timesheet reporting using the Calendar API. How do I access the label strings associated with each color ID?

The [Colors resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/colors) (2022-12-19 version) only provides foreground and background color data, no label string. Also the [Settings resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/settings) (2022-12-19 version) does not provide what I need. I have also tried the [CalDAV API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) (2022-12-19 version) but that does not seem to provide color or label information at all.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/colors/get?apix=true#try-it   ?

Comment: Thanks @Luuk, but that example query from the Colors resource only provides the foreground and background color data. I’m looking for the label strings.

Comment: an [event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) does have a `colorId`, But I do not see a label for that color (see also: [Google Calendar API - PHP - set event's color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346277/google-calendar-api-php-set-events-color) )

Comment: Thanks @Luuk, that reinforces my suspicion that the answer to my question is “you cannot”. I hope someone will prove me wrong. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the actual state there is no way to query the color label of the [`Time Insights`](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/12377581).

You can review the feedback about features and functionality  in Issue Tracker, review if someone has submitted the same one, if not, you can submit a [new feedback report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906).